# How did the screen translation or cursor translation realized?

Tags: winapi, screen, hook, translation

There are many translator softwares like lingoes(灵格斯), xdict（金山词霸）, etc. that could do cursor tranlsation, that is, it can translate the **selected word**(not the word under cursor) in most programs in windows.

I have tried send ctrl+c message or WM_COPY, while this is less effective than those softwares (replace the current clipboard, not work in all softwares, etc.), I am wondering how did it work?

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, those tools employ [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). A tool that both uses UI Automation, and displays the information available to UI Automation is [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx), part of the Windows SDK.